# ruff : E999 SyntaxError on match/case syntax

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.10, linter, ruff

I got a strange issue with ruff (0.0.209) and python 3.10.9 interpreter when I use match/case syntax.
For instance, this simple code :

```py
from http import HTTPStatus

http_status = HTTPStatus.OK

match http_status:
    case HTTPStatus.OK:
        print("OK!")

    case HTTPStatus.BAD_REQUEST:
        print("Bad, bad Zoot!")

    case _:
        print("Just a flesh wound.")
```

Raise a `5:8: E999 SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Got unexpected token 'http_status'`

At the same time, ruff argue that it now support python3.11. Who is lying ? :)

I tried to update ruff with last version

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not supported as of 2023-01-06 unfortunately. This is the [tracking issue](https://github.com/charliermarsh/ruff/issues/282).

**Update (2023-03-11):** Get ruff [0.0.250](https://github.com/charliermarsh/ruff/releases/tag/v0.0.250) or above.

Comment: Thanks ! That's what I've been looking for :)
Its not what I can call "python 3.11 compliant" btw